# Ошибка в слайдере при подгрузке контента без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно было сделать подгрузку контента без перезагрузки страницы и я сделал это так:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('a').click(function(event){
        jQuery('.loading').fadeIn('slow');
        jQuery(window).on('load', function () {
            var $preloader = $('.loading');
        }); 
        var link = $(this).attr("href");
        //jQuery('#wrapload').load(link);
        jQuery.ajax({ 
            url: link, 
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){ 
                jQuery('#wrapload').html(data); 
            } 
        }); 
        jQuery('.loading').fadeOut('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Но на всех страницах присутствует слайдер и когда переходишь по страницам, он иногда выдает вот ошибку:

```
Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 
'Node': The new child element contains the parent.
```

Как решить проблему?

Comment: не проверяли уникальность блока с id **wrapload** на странице где получаете ошибку?

Comment: чисто предположение: data приходит в результате асинхронного запроса. Вероятно, что-то меняется в DOM до момента, когда выполняется вставка html

Comment: нет не проверял она рандомно появляется может появится да же там где только что было все нормально :)

Comment: Mr.Brighrside что подскажете сделать что бы это исправить ?

Comment: Другого кода на странице нету?